# Cython import explanation

Tags: python, cython

On line 26 [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/robotics/robot_env.py) we have this line:

```
self.sim = mujoco_py.MjSim(model, nsubsteps=n_substeps)
```

The mujoco_py MjSim file is here: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/blob/master/mujoco_py/mjsim.pyx

I don't understand how this cython is working. I read the cython tutorial but it wasnt making sense: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html

Specifically, in python we would have to do: mujoco_py.mjsim.MjSim() to instantiate the MjSim object. How exactly is cython loading things such that the MjSim object is callable immediately after mujoco_py?

Also, in line 155 here: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/blob/master/mujoco_py/mjrendercontext.pyx

There is a call mjv_updateScene(...). Where is this function defined?

Comment: Please read [ask] you are supposed to provide a [mcve] as the question must be understandable without the need to follow links.

Comment: I don't understand how the cython code works so it is not possible for me to produce a minimal example

Comment: "Specifically, in python we would have to do: mujoco_py.mjsim.MjSim() to instantiate the MjSim object" - you missed the `__init__.py` where it has `MjSim = cymj.MjSim
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is \_\_init\_\_.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18979314/4657412) answers your question (which is what @JustinEzequiel has told you)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to second bit of the question about `mjv_updateScene` that you edited in is: "they have the most awful build system I've seen that makes no sense whatsoever".

I believe (although it's difficult to trace all the way back) that [cymj.pyx](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/blob/9ca102f0a3cd744014273191d7f79d0e9fff24ee/mujoco_py/cymj.pyx) is the only .pyx file that's actually built. This file manually (textually) includes all the other .pyx files. This disobeys two conventions: first  things should be cimported rather than textually included (the textual include is only really kept around as an artefact of an earlier way of doing things), and second that included files should be named ".pxi" to indicate that they're being included (then at least you know it isn't self-contained). Instead included files are named a mixture of .pxi, .pyx or .pxd with no regards to their role.

`mjv_updateScene` itself is defined in [pxd/mujoco.pxd](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/blob/d98011924f25466ea5c3819e0460ff8de90e24a2/mujoco_py/pxd/mujoco.pxd) which is included indirectly from [generated/wrappers.pxi](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/blob/7642e61fedf46382a1da835784ac9eab30053ea3/mujoco_py/generated/wrappers.pxi).

I don't know anything about this library but the fact they thought this arrangement was a good idea gives me severe doubts about the quality of everything else. (However, there may be good reasons for it - we've all made dubious-looking bodge-jobs on occasion...)

---

The initial question about `MjSim` is answered in @JustinEzequiel's comment about `__init__.py`.

Comment: Yep found update scene. So is the PXD file just 'exposing' the functions in mujoco.h C header file for python?

Comment: Could you explain the general build flow. I'm just lost as to how I can add more functionality to this python wrapper mujoco_py

Comment: I believe I can add my own python functions to any of the .pyx files. For example, "mjv_makeConnector" in mujoco.pxd is not used in any of the pyx files, so I believe I can add a new python function using it to mjrendercontext.pyx. And then the next time I import mujoco_py, I can use my new function? Or do i need to build it?

Comment: Yes - that's what pxd files are (mainly) for - to "expose" C functions. In well-written code they're either statically imported with `cimport`, or if they have the same name as a pyx file they're then it's kind of the same as `from name cimport *` automatically.

Comment: I honestly could not clearly explain the general build flow. It's a mess and I gave up trying to understand it all. However: if you edit "mjrendercontext.pyx" you will need to rebuild it to use your new function (this is definitely true!); to rebuild it you'd normally do something similar to "python setup.py build_ext", but with this code it's hard to be certain...